# What's the proper nginx config for web app with XSL / The "getAttribute" property of an undefined or null reference cannot be retrieved

Tags: xml, nginx, xslt, xmlhttprequest, nginx-config

So there is a rather complex but well developed web application from 2016 from a very big company everyone knows. I am currently implementing it in a customer's system.
It is a web application simply running with HTML, JS, CSS and XML. In some part it uses XSL though and this seems to create a problem, at least for the configuration I currently have, which is the standard nginx mainline config.
I have seen this web application running fine elsewhere (unknown config) and if I try it with github pages it also works fine.

I ran it with nginx and lighttpd on GNU/Linux and on Windows 10 x64.
It doesn't work with current Chromium, Firefox or Edge on GNU/Linux and Windows.
But it does to some extend work with Internet Explorer on Windows; It shows an error and then displays the html frame missing some functionality (zooming a graphic/image).
This is the error I get trying with IE (translated to english):

> The "getAttribute" property of an undefined or null reference cannot
> be retrieved.

I tried nginx-debug with the debug flag for the log file and the only thing I found scraping through the log was that it only appeared when a XSL file was involved.
Using the Developer Tools of Chromium and Firefox does not show any issue or error. Odd!

So it seems to be something related to XML/XSL/XSLT and my web server config. It is not a bug of the web app, since it is known to run well on many systems incl. github pages.

Here is the nginx.conf:

( I tried with `load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;` and without)

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Here is the mime.types:

```
types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/avif                                       avif;
    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/wasm                                 wasm;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}
```

And here is the web apps own server.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location = /status {
       access_log off;
       default_type text/plain;
       add_header Content-Type text/plain;
       return 200 "alive";
    }
       
    location / {
       gzip off;
       root /var/www/html/;
       index  index.html;
    }
}
```

And some info on the nginx install:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.21.5
built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.21.5/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.21.5=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
```

I wonder if I need to specify certain parameters to the nginx config?

Comment: 'The "getAttribute" property of an undefined or null reference cannot be retrieved' sounds like a Javascript error message where e.g. `node.getAttribute('...')` is called while node is undefined or null, for instance because e.g. `var node = document.getElementById('someId')` didn't find a node. Normally the browser will indicate the line number and file name where the script error occured.

Comment: The error sadly did not indicate the line number or so.

Finally I got it working by using the IP instead, in this case 127.0.0.1 instead of locahost and now everything works fine. Strange. I'll be looking into it further and will leave results here eventually.

Comment: Using localhost as domain does not work, but using literally anything else does. Even when using localhost as servername it doesn't. I just specified localhosttest in my hosts file as 127.0.0.1 and as servername in the server.conf and that does work indeed. Seems to be some sort of restriciton on using localhost as domain name. Didn't find the cause yet, though.